# gmail api returning total messages as 0 for a particular Label

Tags: gmail-api

I have been using the "Get Label" API to get the details of a particular Label.

It was all working until the last couple of days.

What I now observe is that the "Total Messages" Count is always 0. "UnRead Messages" Count show up properly.

I have used it in my application and also tried it from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get - "Try It Now" and the result is the same --- 0 Total Messages

Comment: Does it do that for other labels for you or just that one? Specifically other user labels and other system labels? Is it just messagesTotal? (are threadsUnread, threadsTotal and messagesUnread correct?)

Comment: @EricDeFriez Only for a particular label, MessagesTotal and threadsTotal show as 0. The other fields are populated correctly.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  What happens when you view that label in the Gmail web interface?  (Does it correctly show the message count on the left label bar?)

Comment: On the left Label Bar it shows only Unread Message Count, which is returned correct anyways.

I have also created a new Label now and it shows the Messages correctly for this new Label. But the older one still fails.

Comment: When you click on that label to view the thread list view it should show toward the top-right something like "1-100 of ____" is that correct there?  (That should show either messagesTotal or threadsTotal depending on your settings.)  After doing that it still is wrong through API?  Did you create that label through API?

Comment: I am facing the same issue - threads count appears correctly in gmail view, its still wrong through API, label was created through IMAP Api - there is a bug posted here: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3785&q=gmail-api&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner as well, but no real activity there.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments to the question, there's an apparent bug in the API as reported [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3785&q=gmail-api&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner).

FWIW I'm running into the same issue.

In my case I have three accounts, all created programmatically by the same code, all containing messages inserted programmatically by the same code. The get label API repeatably reports the correct number of messages for one account while erroneously reporting zero messages for the other two accounts. Viewing the account in the web interface shows all the messages in all the accounts as expected.