# Gmail labels.get() returns the wrong counts

Tags: gmail-api

I'm currently using the [labels.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get) call to sync unread counts for inboxes...

```
gmail.users.labels.get({
    userId: 'me',
    id: 'INBOX',
    auth: { ... }
}, (err, response) => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

... for the most part this works, but some users are reporting incorrect counts. For example I have one account that in the Gmail UI reports 11 unread threads, then searching for `label:inbox label:unread` also reports 11, however the response from `label.get()` reports 21 in `threadsUnread`.

The count on some accounts seems to be consistently higher than the actual count. Is there anything else I can do here to get the correct count, or is there anything that can be done in the Gmail UI to force the label to update?

I have noticed there's an outstanding bug where certain accounts return 0, but this seems like a different behaviour to that [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777890/gmail-api-returning-total-messages-as-0-for-a-particular-label) [Googlecode](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3785&q=gmail-api&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Gmail API and has been reported [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3785&q=gmail-api&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner).